# InvalidJSON. The 'content' property of actions of type 'ParseJson' must be valid JSON

Tags: azure-logic-apps

i try to get json file from **azure blob storage account** and check the Expires field in that json if Expires is less than comming 2 month need to send a email with that data.

The issue is ...

> InvalidJSON. The 'content' property of actions of type 'ParseJson' must be valid JSON in ParseJson

[image]

[image]

[image]

ParseJson input

```
[
    
    {
        "Environment":  "DEV",
        "Application":  "OTHER",
        "Keyvault":  "key-xx-dd",
        "Secret":  "secrect1",
        "Expires":  "2023-10-19T12:51:20+00:00"
    },
    {
        "Environment":  "DEV",
        "Application":  "OTHER",
        "Keyvault":  "key-xx-dd",
        "Secret":  "secrect2",
        "Expires":  "2023-10-19T12:51:20+00:00"
    },
    
    {
        "Environment":  "DEV",
        "Application":  "OTHER",
        "Keyvault":  "key-xx-dd",
        "Secret":  "secrect3",
        "Expires":  "2023-10-19T12:51:20+00:00"
    }
]
```

JsonSchema

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "Application": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Environment": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Expires": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Keyvault": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Secret": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "Environment",
      "Application",
      "Keyvault",
      "Secret",
      "Expires"
    ]
  }
}
```

Raw input ParseJson

```
{
    "content": "[\r\n    \r\n    {\r\n        \"Environment\":  \"DEV\",\r\n        \"Application\":  \"OTHER\",\r\n        \"Keyvault\":  \"key-xx-dd\",\r\n        \"Secret\":  \"secrect1\",\r\n        \"Expires\":  \"2023-10-19T12:51:20+00:00\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        \"Environment\":  \"DEV\",\r\n        \"Application\":  \"OTHER\",\r\n        \"Keyvault\":  \"key-xx-dd\",\r\n        \"Secret\":  \"secrect2\",\r\n        \"Expires\":  \"2023-10-19T12:51:20+00:00\"\r\n    },\r\n    \r\n    {\r\n        \"Environment\":  \"DEV\",\r\n        \"Application\":  \"OTHER\",\r\n        \"Keyvault\":  \"key-xx-dd\",\r\n        \"Secret\":  \"secrect3\",\r\n        \"Expires\":  \"2023-10-19T12:51:20+00:00\"\r\n    }\r\n]\r\n",
    "schema": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Application": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Environment": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Expires": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Keyvault": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Secret": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "Environment",
                "Application",
                "Keyvault",
                "Secret",
                "Expires"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: images - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/54FW4.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOr7S.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpXbl.png

Comment: Edit your question and add the images.

Comment: i couldn't add those images

Comment: i need at least 10 reputation to post images can you please add those images

Comment: You need to paste your JSON as text into the question.  Impossible to help without it.  By the looks of it though, you have a dodgy character at the start.  Drop us the exact text and we may be able to solve it for you.

Comment: @SureshSuji Try to copy and paste the content in Notepad++ and enable view-->Show Symbols-->Show Non printing character, you will be able to see there is character in the blob content itself. In order to see it in Notepad, try to save your file in ANSI format, you will see one `?`

Comment: @Skin I have added JSON into the question

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin  character  is not in blob content, how to fix this?

Comment: @SureshSuji Surprisingly you will not be able to see the character if you copy and paste the blob content. You could try to open the file which you have uploaded to the blob storage in Notepad and save as like [this](https://i.imgur.com/ptsp4tj.png) and re-upload it the new file as a blob

Comment: @SureshSuji added an alternative solution, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a `ZWNBSP` character which is getting amended in content of `Parse_JSON` action. You will not be able to see it in Notepad or in blob content's edit option but can be seen in Notepad++ with View --> Show Symbols --> Show Non-printing Characters.

[image]

There are two ways you can fix it.

1. Manually remove it and re-upload the file to the blob storage and then trigger your logic app.
2. You could also add `Html to Text` action to fix this issue.

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]